# Application not getting open from deeplinking url

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have completely setup branch.io and generated few links to test. It was working fine. But I need to change the account for branch and I created a new account with branch and copied all settings from the previous account I created generated the link and in the application, I changed the key, app domain in plist and added applinks to entitlements.

As everything was working fine with the previous account it should be fine with the new account but it doesn't open the application. When I tried with previous account links it did open the application.

When I debugged the link generated with the new account was retrieved in session params when I opened the app.

Comment: It seems like issue from backend. I tried it after half and hour now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: there is currently a delay of up to 15 minutes in generating the `apple-app-site-association` file for new app domains. If you were testing prior to this process completing, then Universal Links would not have been working (which matches the symptoms you describe) yet.

We're working to eliminate this delay in the near future!